# Rails - Table Filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that can be filtered by name, date.. etc.. BUT after I edit or destroy an item it resets all of my filters.. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to edit and destroy and NOT reset my filters?

Thank you!

edit**
I am using ransack for filters

```
 <%= search_form_for @q, class: 'form-inline auto-submit' do |f| %>
      <%= f.label(:name_cont, 'Name', class: 'col-form label') %>
      <div class="col-auto">
        <%= f.search_field(:name_cont, class: 'form-control')%>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: I added my ransack code! Is that okay? Do I need to provide more?

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts here. Can you reproduce this in a brand-new rails app? How about without ransack? In the process of producing that [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll probably learn a lot! Good luck.

Comment: This is how I solved this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290313/persisting-search-queries