# Persisting search queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm using this code to persist my ransack filters when the user destroys the item.

```
# In application controller
def get_query(cookie_key)
    cookies.delete(cookie_key) if params[:clear]
    cookies[cookie_key] = params[:q].to_json if params[:q]
    @query = params[:q].presence || JSON.load(cookies[cookie_key])
  end
 
# In my example controller
before_action only: [:index] do
    get_query('example_capabilities')
  end


def destroy
    authorize @example
    @example.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: get_query('example_capabilities'), notice: 'example was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I'd like to use this when the user edit's the item as well but I am not getting the same results. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: `before_action` has only `index` listed which means `get_query()` will be called only for `index`, did you try adding `edit` action to it?

Comment: Yes, it works for edit now. But only when I click the back button in edit. If I continue on and go to show it says that my account is not authorized to do that.

Comment: This is what I tried using in show ``` def show
    authorize @capability
    respond_to do |format|
      if @capability.show
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: get_query('query_capabilities')}
      end
    end

  end```

Comment: since it throws an error related to authorization, there must be something wrong with the capability object. Also, I'm not sure if calling `@capability.show` is the right way to check and its also not required.